# How to update a record in SQL bypassing NHibernate version control

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, proxy

Just suppose I have a table with a `timestamp` column that used via `NHibernate` to manage record version, Now I'm looking for a way to update a record of my data **without** increase the value of ts column, Because as you know that value would increase after each update statement to track version of data for avoid concurrency issues.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TSTest]( 
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL, 
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
    [ts] [timestamp] NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TSTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ASC )
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Any idea?

Comment: no, you cannot.

Comment: I think it would be possible, Nothing is impossible in software !

Comment: Thank you for edit @Serg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are *certain columns* that should not be subject to `timestamp` tracking then you can move those columns into a new table that then refers back to this original table.

If desired, you can hide the existence of this new table and the modified original table from the application by then producing a view called `TSTest` that joins the tables together (together with triggers that apply inserts, updates and deletes to the appropriate base tables).

However, in this instance it's not clear what we should do since there's only one obvious "updatable" column - `Name` - and so if we don't want it subject to `timestamp` tracking, it's unclear why we have it on this table at all.

Unfortunately, there are no other T-SQL mechanisms to avoid `timestamp`s behaviour - and this is usually seen as a good thing. You can't do anything via triggers since if you actually touch the base table, the `timestamp` will get changed, and you're not allowed to `UPDATE` timestamp columns so you can't even reset it after change.

> I think it would be possible, Nothing is impossible in software

Leaving aside the existence of things like the halting problem, you are of course correct that this problem *can* be solved - but not in a way that's likely to be useful to you. As I've said above, it's not possible through T-SQL.

If you *really* need to do this then you can do it by directly manipulating the database file. Of course, that requires you to detach the database or take the server down, and to then pore through the file structures to manually locate the page(s) the contain the rows you wish to alter, then to apply those changes and then to correct other parts of the structure (such as page checksums) so that SQL Server doesn't believe that the pages are now corrupt.

I'm not really advocating this approach, just outlining how far away from normality you'd have to go to actually perform what you're asking for.

Comment: I liked your answer because of your wide opinion to solve this question, Just for your information this table schema is just for test my original table is another one, By the way I'm interested in you second solution that recommend me to use View, I think it would be work for my situation, Thank you my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea?

Per your comment and schema your `ts` column `[ts] [timestamp] NOT NULL`. So it would get modified on every update operation.

One way could be using a `AFTER UPDATE` trigger and undoing the modification happened. But why would you do that? Moreover, trigger on the same table (or) recursive trigger is not supported in MySQL.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TSTest](
 [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [ts] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TSTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: No, it's a `timestamp` (aka `rowversion`) column, *not* a datetime. So the mention of `current_timestamp`and triggers is a red herring.

Comment: @MohammadNikravesh - when people ask for schema (usually as a comment, rather than in an answer), it's usually best to *edit* your question so that you can mark the block as code (`{}`) so that it's *readable*, unlike in the comments. (Of course, ideally we wouldn't have to ask for the schema and it would be in your question from the start)

Comment: Oh, Yes you are right, Thank you for your nice advise I will do it :)